# Shell script to extract recursive xml tags

Tags: xml, bash, shell, sed

I have an XML file of form:

```
...
<element1>
<element2>
<group1>
<tag1>value</tag1>
<tag2>value</tag2>
</group1>
<group1>
<tag1>value</tag1>
<tag2>value</tag2>
</group1>
<element2>
...
```

I used

```
sed -n '/\<group1\>/,\<\/group1>/p' filename
```

to extract all content of group1 tags, including all childs. This is exactly what I want.

```
<group1>
<tag1>value</tag1>
<tag2>value</tag2>
</group1>
<group1>
<tag1>value</tag1>
<tag2>value</tag2>
</group1>
```

However, if the input XML is of form

```
...
<element1>
<element2>
<group2>
     <group2>value</group2>
     <otherTag>value</otherTag>
</group2>
<element3>
<group2>
     <group2>value</group2>
     <otherTag>value</otherTag>
</group2>
...
```

And I tried to extract following content

```
<group2>
     <group2>value</group2>
     <otherTag>value</otherTag>
</group2>
<group2>
     <group2>value</group2>
     <otherTag>value</otherTag>
</group2>
```

The sed command above just returns:

```
<group2>
     <group2>value</group2>
```

It understands the stop pattern `</group2>` and do no more extraction. I'm quite confused here. Why doesn't it continue extracting the next `<group2>`, as in `<group1>` case. Is there any way to make it work with sed? and any other alternatives?

Comment: Regular expressions do not deal well with recursive structures. I'd suggest choosing a language with a proper XML parser available.

Comment: Obligatory link to http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/78845

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Far better to use XPath with a command line xpath interpreter, like xpath, xmlstarlet, my xidel or xmllint.

All group elements on the 3rd level:

```
/elememt1/*/group1
```

All group elements that do not contain a group2:

```
//group2[not(group2)]
```

Comment: I opted for xmlstarlet, this provides some other great stuff. Thanks

Comment: Well, my Xidel has the advantage that it supports XPath 2 (and XQuery). Xmlstarlet has only XPath 1 ...

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `sed` like this

```
sed -n '/\<group1\>/,/^<\/group1>/p' filename  | grep -v 'element3'
```

Comment: This does not work. It prints out even the <element3> in the middle of 2 <group2>

Answer (score 0):

Some like this?

```
awk '/^<group2>/,/^<\/group2>/' file
<group2>
     <group2>value</group2>
     <otherTag>value</otherTag>
</group2>
<group2>
     <group2>value</group2>
     <otherTag>value</otherTag>
</group2>
```

This works if there are different spacing on the tag, if all is adjusted to the left, it will not work